# Does SQLite cordova plugin (litehelpers) support INSTR, ORDER BY DESC and LIMIT OFFSET for SELECT queries?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite, cordova-plugins

Im thinking to include litehelpers plugin in my project and I saw in their docs that ORDER BY DESC and LIMIT OFFSET is not supported for UPDATE/DELETE queries  but Im not sure if its possible to use them (and INSTR) with SELECT.

Can anybody confirm this?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't used LIMIT in the SELECT but I confirm you can use the ORDER BY clause in this sqlite plugin.

Comment: Thank you Zappescu

Comment: Don't forget to validate my answer please :)

Comment: Alright, also I saw in sqlite documentation that LIMIT is not in the  list of features supported by sqlite